# How can I run a servlet programme?

Tags: java

How can I run a servlet programme?How can i set the classpath?

Comment: Duplicate- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724149/how-to-run-servlet-programs

Answer (score 2):

Please read this http://www.jsptube.com/servlet-tutorials/simple-servlet-example.html for your first steps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you generally run it in a servlet container such as Websphere Application Server or Tomcat. And the way you configure the classpath depends on the servlet container you choose.

Answer (score 0):

just to repeat the basics: a servlet is a piece of java code that runs inside a servlet container (i.e. a spezialized web server). it listens to client requests (typically issued through a web browser) and answers them with a response (e.g. with an HTML page).

"running" a servlet can thus mean two different things:

1. deploying the servlet to a servlet container (and thereby making it listen to requests), or
2. actually making it process a client request

(1) is achieved by packaging the servlet code (+ 3rd party libraries) into a [war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(Sun_file_format)) file and deploying this web application archive to the server -- details may vary depending on the type of servlet container. (2) is triggered by issuing a http request, e.g. through typing the servlet URL (something like `http://localhost:8080/servletexample`) into the location bar of your browser.